# Trying to parse links in an HTML directory listing using Java regex

Tags: java, html, android, regex

Ok I know everyone is going to tell me not to use RegEx for parsing HTML, but I'm programming on Android and don't have ready access to an HTML parser (that I'm aware of). Besides, this is server generated HTML which *should* be more consistent than user-generated HTML.

The regex looks like this:

```
Pattern patternMP3 = Pattern.compile(
        "<A HREF=\"[^\"]+.+\\.mp3</A>",
        Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE |
        Pattern.UNICODE_CASE);
Matcher matcherMP3 = patternMP3.matcher(HTML);
while (matcherMP3.find()) { ... }
```

The input HTML is all on one line, which is causing the problem. When the HTML is on separate lines this pattern works. Any suggestions?

Comment: Could you give an example of a link?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The regex

```
"<A HREF=\"([^\"]+)\"[^>]*>([^<]+?)\\.mp3</A>"
```

should match your links, and have the link and the filename in its groups.
Note though, that the argument of `href` does not neccesarily need to be enclosed in quotes in html. (Or, if it needs to be, neither browsers nor developers know that =). )

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be matching '.+' since you've already got [^\"]+ (which is better for your particular situation).

Try:

```
"<A HREF=\"[^\"]+\\.mp3\"</A>"
```

Also, don't forget the double-quote after the mp3.

Comment: Not getting any matches with this. Note that I'm attempting to capture all text after <A HREF=" and before .mp3</A>. I need both the hyperlink and file name, which I parse later.

Answer (score 0):

For your information, on Android you can parse HTML 'properly' with a combination of  org.cyberneko.html.parsers.SAXParser, org.xml.sax.* and org.dom4j.*.

http://sourceforge.net/projects/nekohtml

http://www.saxproject.org

http://dom4j.sourceforge.net