# Need help modifying regular expression

Tags: java, regex

One of these days I'll get good at regex but for now...

I'm parsing an HTML page looking for MP3 files using the following expression (which works):

```
"<A HREF=\"([^\"]+)\"[^>]*>([^<]+?)\\.mp3</A>"
```

I now want to search for both MP3 and OGG files. Seems like a simple OR modification (.mp3 || .ogg), but I'm not quite sure how I put that in there? See [Trying to parse links in an HTML directory listing using Java regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2542559) for more info.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Understanding the pattern

You have the following Java string literal:

```
// Java string literal
"<A HREF=\"([^\"]+)\"[^>]*>([^<]+?)\\.mp3</A>"
```

The pattern represented by this string, when all escape sequences are processed, is this:

```
// the regex pattern
<A HREF="([^"]+)"[^>]*>([^<]+?)\.mp3</A>
```

Now let's break this pattern apart:

```
_________       _     _        E________
<A HREF="([^"]+)"[^>]*>([^<]+?)\.mp3</A>
         \_____/       \______/
            1              2
```

So the parts of this regex are:

1. `<A HREF="` matched literally
2. `([^"]+)`, i.e. everything but doublequotes, captured in group 1
3. `"` mached literally
4. `[^>]*`, i.e. everything but `>`
5. `>` matched literally
6. `([^<]+?)`, i.e. everything but `<`, as few as possible, captured in group 2
7. `.mp3</A>` matched literally (the `.` is escaped by backslash)

So looking at this, we can observe that the regex makes the following assumptions:

- The `href` attribute value is matched by part 2; it must be enclosed in doublequotes, and itself can not contain any escaped doublequotes. This match is captured into group 1.
- Any remaining attributes is matched by part 4. The `href` must be the first attribute, or else the regex wouldn't match.
- Part 6 matches the filename, capturing into group 2.
- Part 7 matches the extension, and immediately after, the closing element. The reluctance of part 6 is probably not necessary.

Parsing HTML with regex is a tricky business, but given numerous assumptions, the above regex seems capable of doing the job most of the time.

---

#### Modifying the pattern

[Alternation](http://www.regular-expressions.info/alternation.html) in regex is done using the vertical bar. It's important to understand its precedence, and how grouping can be useful.

- `this|that` matches one of these two strings:

  - `"this"`
  - `"that"`
- `this|that thing` matches one of these two strings:

  - `"this"`
  - `"that thing"`
- `(this|that) thing` matches one of these two strings:

  - `"this thing"`
  - `"that thing"`
- `(this|that) (thing|stuff)` matches one of these four strings:

  - `"this thing"`
  - `"that thing"`
  - `"this stuff"`
  - `"that stuff"`

So to allow both `mp3` and `ogg` extension, we can modify the `mp3` in the pattern to `(mp3|ogg)`. Note that this group will match and capture the extension into group 3.

The final pattern, therefore, is:

```
<A HREF="([^"]+)"[^>]*>([^<]+)\.(mp3|ogg)</A>
         \_____/       \_____/  \_______/
          1:url      2:filename   3:ext
```

As a Java string literal, this is:

```
"<A HREF=\"([^\"]+)\"[^>]*>([^<]+)\\.(mp3|ogg)</A>"
```

---

#### Appendix

The `[…]` is a [*character class*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html). Something like `[aeiou]` matches one of any of the lowercase vowels. `[^…]` is a *negated* character class. `[^aeiou]` matches one of *anything but* the lowercase vowels.

The `(…)` is a [*capturing group*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/brackets.html). It allows the string that it matched to be retrieved later.

The `*` and `+` are [*repetition specifiers*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html). By default, repetition is greedy (i.e. match as *much* as possible). The `?` in `+?` makes it reluctant (i.e. match as *few* as possible).

Note that `?` may also serve as [*optional repetition specifier*](http://www.regular-expressions.info/optional.html) in other contexts.

The `.` is a metacharacter that [matches (almost) any character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html). Since we want a literal period, we escape it by preceding with doubleslash.

Note that regex pattern is by default case sensitive. In Java, you may want to use [`Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#CASE_INSENSITIVE) flag (embeddable as `(?i)` in the pattern).

Comment: +1 instead of just giving an answer, you really went above and beyond, explaining how and why. You are the type of person that SO needs more of.

Answer (score 4):

```
Replace 
    \.mp3
with
    \.((mp3)|(ogg))
```

And beware of parsing HTML with regex.

Comment: Why double parentheses? `\.(mp3|ogg)` would be sufficient

Comment: I put in extra parentheses because my preconscious parses (this|that) as matching thishat or thithat, and I have to override consciously by applying precedence rules.